# Merge/combine BaseX databases with upserts in memory constrained environment

Tags: java, xml, memory, xquery, basex

I have two databases in BaseX, `source_db` and `target_db`, and would like to merge them by matching on the `id` attribute of each element and upserting the element with a `replace` or an `insert` depending on whether the element was found in the `target_db`. `source_db` has about 100,000 elements, and `target_db` has about 1,000,000 elements.

```xml
<!-- source_db contents -->
<root>
  <element id="1">
  <element id="2">
</root>
<!-- target_db contents -->
<root>
  <element id="1">
</root>
```

My query to merge the two databases looks like this:

```xq
for $e in (db:open("source_db")/root/element)
return (
  if (exists(db:open("target_db")/root/element[@id = data($e/@id)]))
  then replace node db:open("target_db")/root/element[@id = data($e/@id)] with $e
  else insert node $e into db:open("target_db")/root
)
```

When running the query, however, I keep getting memory constraint errors. Using a [POST request to BaseX's REST interface](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#POST_Method) I get `Out of Main Memory` and using the [BaseX java client](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/api/BaseXClient.java) I get `java.io.IOException: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

Ideally I would like to just process one element from `source_db` at a time to avoid memory issues, but it seems like my query isn't doing this. I've tried using the `db:copynode false` pragma but it did not make a difference. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I do not know BaseX but does it have something similar to exist-db batch transaction?

Comment: Or use another (hackish) solution would be using the file system. Write out the updates as files, then separately apply the update reading those files back in.